# If rocket engines only need fuel and oxidizer, then why there are so many pipe lines on the engines?

Tags: rockets, engine-design, merlin-1d, ssme, raptor

[image: RS-25]

If fuel and oxidizer are pumped by turbines to the combustion chamber, then why there are so many pipes around? It should only have a two-cylinder shaped turbine assembly.  I doubt there are other gases also pushed in other than fuel and oxidizer.

Comment: you only need one blood and how many vessels do yo have?

Comment: Annotate your image to point out one (1) of the "pipes" on this SSME and I'll tell you what it's for.

Comment: Jet engines don't even need oxidizer: have a look at the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_J58)...

Comment: The difference you see is the difference between science and engineering, or similarly, theory and practice. [Science](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Brayton_cycle.svg/1920px-Brayton_cycle.svg.png) vs [Engineering](https://blog.klm.com/assets/uploads/2016/03/motoren-test-2.jpg)

Comment: To get an idea of what some of those pipes are for, here is a fairly in depth explanation of SpaceX's new raptor engine: https://everydayastronaut.com/raptor-engine/

Answer (score 50, accepted):

While an ideal engine would just ingest fuel and oxidizer and produce exhaust gas real world engines will have some combination of [regenerative cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_cooling_(rocket)), [film cooling](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38301/kerosene-engine-film-cooling), [turbine exhaust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staged_combustion_cycle), [hydraulic power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrust_vectoring), [ignition systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triethylborane), pressure sensing, [tank pressurization systems](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6323/disposition-of-the-oxidizer-tank-in-rockets-with-autogenous-pressurization), drain/purge/test lines, and electrical connections that just [look like pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral-insulated_copper-clad_cable) for heat protection, and are probably majority of the 'plumbing' [visible in the question photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-25#Controller). Some of these may also have bypass or redundant connections.

The possible contents are liquid fuel, liquid oxidiser, vaporised fuel, vaporised oxidiser, fuel rich turbine exhaust, oxidiser rich turbine exhaust, fully burned exhuast, hydraulic pressure, hydraulic return (possibly multiples of these if valves outside engine, ignition system fluids, pneumatic system gases, electricity.

Examples of engines using various combinations
[Rs-25/SSME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-25)
[RL-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL10)
[F1/Saturn V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne_F-1)
[Merlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Merlin)
[Rutherford/Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab_Rutherford) (possibly the simplest plumbing of a current engine)

Comment: Your link to film cooling isn't actually about film cooling! You'll note the exhausterator is at the end of the nozzle--there's nothing to cool beyond that.

Comment: @Anton Hengest, you would be right, had thought it was at the end of the nozzle and then cooled the nozzle extension but that is not correct. There is a more relevant one there now though still have not found a really good ref for the concept.

Comment: The F-1 is really the ur-example for film-cooled nozzles

Comment: WTH the Rutherford, I thought the whole reason they use turbopumps was that the energy required by the pumps was stupefyingly large compared to possible output for piston engines, battery electric etc.  I guess that is not so after all.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Battery power to weight ratios have gotten drastically better in recent years, so the Rutherford approach isn't completely impractical, though I don't know if it's actually lighter or heavier than the equivalent power turbopump & turbopump fuel.

Comment: @RussellBorogove if battery power is so good, then how come gasoline energy density is the only thing that can — *(browses Tesla website... looks at Tesla Supercharger map) **Okay then**.  Anyway where were we...* Yeah you have a good point, the battery only has to weigh less than the fuel they waste running the turbopumps.

Comment: Well, more precisely, it's (battery + electric motor) versus (propellant + turbopump).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Well off topic now but my understanding was the batteries for electron weight more than the fuel+turbine would have, but it allowed them to side step a lot of design complications in a new engine so made sense.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica gasoline energy density _is_ still very favourable compared to batteries – in the automobile domain. However, that only plays out fully because cars don't need to carry their oxidizer, and don't need their engines to be insanely powerful yet still light and robust to a very hostile environment. All of that makes efficiency yet a lot worse than combustion engines are anyway. An electric drivetrain meanwhile is pretty much rocket-ready from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

The tubes built into the nozzle perform to very necessary functions.

1. the very very, super cold, super dense liquid in these pipes keeps the nozzle from melting or really deforming and becoming too inefficient.
   When wondering about rockets always consider cost to efficiency and performance to weight. Engines manufactured  in higher volumes must meet these criteria.
   The liquid in the pipes that are part of the nozzle is the super super sub cold and dense fuel. To give up its energy the best way requires it to be a specific temp.
   The bigger nozzle pipes protects the integrity of the nozzle and preheats the fuel.

Comment: Can you confirm the fluid in the nozzle cooling pipes is "super dense"? For the SSME the H2 exiting the coolant circuit had a density of about 2.5 lbm/ft^3.